# Swift optional nil check returns different result than actual case

Tags: swift

`taker` is a dictionary. When I check `taker["user_id"]` for nil value. It says it is not nil. But when I unwraps it actually contains null value. Here is my debugger output. How is this possible?

[image: Debugger output]

Comment: If your dictionary is like `let dictionary: [String: AnyObject] = ["id": NSNull()]` then `dictionary["id"] = Optional(<null>)` but when you check for nil i,e it will return as non nil value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`po taker["user_id"]` gives you the correct answer: `Some: <null>` means that what's inside the nullable value is null. Even without Foundation interop, you could get something similar with a dictionary of optional values (like `[Int: Int?]`, in which case the subscript's result type would be `Int??`).

In your case, though, it's "just" that the object in the optional is an instance of `NSNull()`. `NSNull` is a special type that you use in places where `nil` would not be acceptable. For instance, Objective-C NSDictionaries do not support `nil` values (as they return `nil` for keys that are absent in the dictionary). If you want to signal that a `NSDictionary` key exists but has no value, the most common thing to do is to associate it to a `NSNull` value.

I suspect that `taker` is a dictionary derived from JSON. You should check that, additionally to the key being present, the value has the type that you expect. This will weed out `NSNull`s and possibly other incorrect inputs. For instance:

```
if let value = taker["user_id"] as? Int {
    // things here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be the case

You dictionary contains NSNull() as value

```
let dictionary: [String: AnyObject] = ["id": NSNull()]

if dictionary["id"] == nil {
    print("is Nil")
}else {
    print("Not Nil")  // prints:  Not Nil as this is true 
}

print(dictionary["id"]) // Optional(<null>)
```